# dataframe to rdd python / spark / pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

i'm using a somewhat old pyspark script.
and i'm trying to convert a dataframe df to rdd.

```
#Importing the required libraries
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressor
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession     .builder     .appName("Python Spark")     .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")

# read the data
df = pd.read_json("events.json")

df = (df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[1],[x[0]])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).sortBy(lambda k_v: (k_v[0], sorted(k_v[1], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))).collect())
```

heres the error output:
**AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rdd'**

what am i missing? 
how do i transform a dataframe to rdd?

i got anaconda 3.6.1 and spark 2.3.1 installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df = pd.read_json("events.json")`: your df is not a pyspark DataFrame, it is a Pandas DataFrame so it has no rdd attribute.

To create a pyspark DataFrame from a json, use `df = sqlContext.jsonFile('events.json')`